# Proof regarding an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Consider a sequence b<sub>n</sub> with values in ℝ, indexed by ℕ. Suppose the range of  b<sub>n</sub> is contained in the finite interval [a, b]. By subdividing [a, b] into 2 intervals of equal lengths [a, <sup>b+a</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>) and [<sup>b+a</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>, b] prove that one of them must contain infinitely many terms of the sequence.

Sounds very similar to a pidgeonhole problem, Since the sequence is infinite, then at least one of the subdividing intervals would also have to have infinitely many terms. I am confused as to how I would prove this though

Comment: The sentence you gave would be good enough for most people.  If you really wanted, you could pursue an alternative "proof by contradiction" approach.  Or more simply, at the end of your sentence you could put ", otherwise,..."

Comment: You could mention that if they both contain finitely many terms, say $n,m$ terms, then let $K = \max\lbrace n,m\rbrace$.  You have that $b_{2K+1}$ must either contain an element outside of $[a,b]$ (a contradition), or have one of the intervals contain more than $K$ elements, another contradiction.